# Spring autowiring not working, getting `applicationDao` as null

Tags: spring, hibernate

Below are my classes and xml:

```
@Component
@Service("ApplicationService")
public class ApplicationServiceImpl implements ApplicationService{

    public ApplicationDao getApplicationDao() {
        return applicationDao;
    }
    public void setApplicationDao(ApplicationDao applicationDao) {
        this.applicationDao = applicationDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationDao applicationDao;

       // some methods..

    }
```

---

```
@Service
 public interface ApplicationService {
 // methods...
}
```

---

```
@Component
@Repository("ApplicationDao")
 public class ApplicationDaoImpl implements ApplicationDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

---

```
public interface ApplicationDao {

   // methods...
}
```

---

xml file:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven/>

   <context:component-scan base-package="com" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> -->
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

       </bean>

<bean id="ApplicationDao" class="com.dao.impl.ApplicationDaoImpl"/>
<bean id="ApplicationService" class="com.service.impl.ApplicationServiceImpl"/>
```

Here autowiring is not working.in `ApplicationServiceImpl`, I am getting `applicationDao` as null. Have not tested `sessionFactory` in ApplicationDaoImpl.

I know that if I am using @Component then bean declaration in xmnl is not required.

Comment: Can you please show the stacktrace you are seeing?

Comment: Try to add `<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>``to your xml file

Comment: There is no exception. I am just getting null while printing dao object.

Comment: @Jens : Its already there. I have updated my question just now.

Comment: You must be making an instance of your class with the new keyword (ie it is the mistake), check it out, and no need to use repository and component at the same time

Comment: @VJS remove the `@Service` annotation from your interface.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt "You must be making an instance of your class with the new keyword" not when you use the spring container.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt : yes in one of the class, I am doing this : ApplicationServiceImpl applicationService = new ApplicationServiceImpl(); applicationService.addApplication(applicationEntity); Should i cant use like this?

Comment: @Jens I meant, check if you are making one, that must be the mistake...

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt :  yes in one of the class, I am doing this : ApplicationServiceImpl applicationService = new ApplicationServiceImpl(); applicationService.addApplication(applicationEntity); Cant i create a obj of ApplicationServiceImpl  like this ??

Comment: @VJS No you should not, that means you are breaking the spring DI flow, autowire or resource inject the field you have marked as component. Never make instance by yourself in these cases

Comment: @VJS remove the bean declarations from your xml file when you use annotations. Do not use more than on annotation of service,component and repository for one object.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt : OK.But if i need ApplicationServiceImpl object in some of my utily class ( or anywhere ) then how will i get it.

Comment: You have to autowire it, or manually inject. Because instantiation of any spring component is decided by spring.

Comment: try removing the new object creation from that class, for an instance, and check if everything works, if it does, then consider manual injection or change your flow of work.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt : ok..let me try.thanks

Comment: Remove your bean definitions and remove `@Component` for your bean, you already have `@Service` and `@Repository`. Add `<context:component-scan base-package="your-package-here" />` to enable scanning for beans and enable annotation driven processing.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt : Thanks...Its working now. Special thanks for the comment you made which says I am doing new my code without seeing my code.

Comment: @VJS thats because, I did it too when I started with spring...many times.

Comment: @VJS I am glad that you got it working

Answer (score 2):

You should not instantiate service like that.. 
At the time of application loading, spring container will create all instances defined in spring.xml or annotated classes and it's dependencies..
So you have to access them with the following example code..

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
            ApplicationService applicationService = (ApplicationService) applicationContext.getBean("ApplicationService");
```

Since `ApplicationService` is having property that is `ApplicationServiceDAOImpl`, it's already been created by spring container and will return you..
But in case of directly instantiating manually by you, you are just creating instance of `ApplicationService` but not for `ApplicationServiceDAOImpl`.. so it obviously returns `null`
I'm currently using this approach only to access beans or services..
**update for comment**

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0)
            throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = arg0;

    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: ok. what is ApplicationContextProvider..this is available in which package / jar.I am not getting it.

Comment: This is an old approach which was used to get beans from application context. With annotations in place, you don't need this anymore.

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary : Thanks. It is useful info.

Answer (score 1):

try a change like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("ApplicationDao")
private ApplicationDao applicationDao;
```

this give spring a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using annotations in your application, you should denote it using a tag :

```
<mvc:annotation-driven  />
```

Add this line in application context xml above component scan tag.
Also, if you are using annotations, remove `ApplicationDao` and `ApplicationService` bean declarations from xml.
And don't mark you service and dao classes with both `@Component` and `@Service` or `@Repository` annotations. No need to mark them `@Component` there. Remove it.

Comment: Adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />` isn't going to do much it enables processing of `@RequestMapping`. Also using `<context:component-scan />` already implies the use of annotation based configuration so no need to add `<context:annotation-driven />` which you probably meant.